# How to hide variable operation in shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Currently on a shopify snippet I have the following tag:

```
{% assign totalQty = 0 | plus: 0 %}

{% for cartItem in cart.items %}
{% if item.product.tags contains 'Work-Hats' %}

  {{ totalQty | plus: cartItem.quantity }}
```

Here I'm doing some addition but I don't want the totalQty to display yet until I'm done compiling a total.

I don't want it to display before I do the operations.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A quantity is always a number. How could it be anything else? It cannot be a decimal, it has to be a whole number. And hopefully, greater than zero, as one cannot have zero of something in their cart.

Comment: Ok but the question was related to how to hide it. I updated it the question.

Comment: Don't output your Liquid till your Loop is over. Outside the endfor you can safely display your total.